# Implementation of branch reordering in GCC

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, linux-kernel, profiling, compiler-optimization

Branch reordering is a profile guided optimization. Does GCC support it? If yes, where/how is the probing/instrumentation actually implemented?

I see that the Linux kernel has a "branch profiling" tracer with 2 levels: likely/unlikely and "all if() constructs"? How does the kernel rely on GCC to actually implement these 2 options? How is the probing/profiling implemented and how is the data read by the kernel?

Answer (score 2):

By default, GCC favors the first part of the if (it acts as if the if would be successful, and the else unsuccesful), but you can use [__builtin_expect](http://www.imodulo.com/gnu/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) to force the branch prediction.